# How do I make Performance Monitor always log the time AND date?

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring, performance-counters

I have been using Performance Monitor to keep an eye on Non-Paged Memory usage over the last few months.  From the csv files generated I have been creating graphs to make it easy to pin point problem periods.  However after awhile (looks like 7 days) the PerfMon logs stop putting in the date with the time.  Actually even the time is truncated to display just the minutes and seconds.

I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that the logs always contain the entire date and time for each record?